# Complete list of Clang flags

Tags: clang

Where can I find a complete list of Clang flags?

There are some, like `-include-pch`, that don't appear to be even listed in the man page. :(

I know that GCC uses some of the same flags, but it doesn't include documentation for stuff like `-Os` which I believe is only available in Clang. Is there a place where I can find a single, consolidated list of all the Clang options ever?

Comment: See [this answer by Chandler Carruth, clang developer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122608/clang-warning-flags-for-objective-c-development/124574#124574).

Comment: Version-dependent options: [Clang warning flags](https://github.com/barro/compiler-warnings#clang-warning-flags). Though it only lists the names of the options (not the documentation).

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want. Maybe more options are described elsewhere, but I think you are interested in the Clang frontend options. By default, the options displayed seem to describe the "GCC-compatible driver".

`clang -cc1 --help` should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best option I've seen so far.

Comment: is there a way to list all possible warnings for `-W<warning>`?

Comment: I don't think so. There is `-Weverything` if you want to activate all of them though. Since Clang tries to be compatible with GCC you can take a look at GCC's ones (`gcc --help=warnings`).

Comment: Some more info here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/124574 and here http://www.noxeos.com/2012/01/10/warning-flags-clang/. Note that `-Weverything` that I mentioned earlier is not for everyday use but more for 'experimentation'.

Comment: @GuillaumePapin can you eleborate on what the '-cc1' option does? I can't find it documented anywhere

Comment: You can see at the [Clang - FAQ](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html#i-run-clang-cc1-and-get-weird-errors-about-missing-headers) that `clang -cc1` is the frontend. `clang` is the GCC-compatible driver. And recently, a new driver has appeared, `clang-cl`, which is a CL-compatible driver. I don't know how to explain `clang -cc1` properly but the word that matters is **frontend**. You should get answers by looking for "compiler frontend", "clang frontend".

Comment: How come none of these places document -shared or -dynamiclib?

Answer (score 8):

There are many hidden options in [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM):

```
clang --help-hidden
opt --help-hidden
```

Answer (score 7):

For Clang, they are listed in the diagnostics reference, which can be found on the documentation website [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html)

Comment: Better: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html

Comment: the command line reference only references -W<warning> but with the diagnostics reference page, you can find that it takes -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage, for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a complete list of ***warning*** flags, including hierarchies (IE which sub-flags are enabled by groups like `-Wall`), you can use the LLVM tool **`diagtool`**.

- **`$ diagtool tree`** Will print the complete list of warnings clang supports.
- **`$ diagtool tree -Wnon-gcc`** will print the warnings enabled by `-Wnon-gcc`.

The warnings are color-coded:

- `RED` = it does nothing, exists only for GCC compatibility
- `GREEN` = the warning is enabled by default
- `YELLOW` = the flag enables new behavior

[image: diagtool-example-wall-flagg=]

---

Finally, I wrote a short script if you're interested in **viewing the diff between sets of flags** (see image below)

For example: `-Wall` -> `-Wall -Wextra` ->`-Wall -Wextra -Wnon-gcc`:

- https://twitter.com/GavinRayDev/status/1599126252136280064
- https://gist.github.com/GavinRay97/c28ca31a86f6a106bb46e426e2603be0

Here is a set of flags not enabled by your typical `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` for Clang (as of LLVM 16 dev) you might find useful, that I scraped from the output of `diagtool`:

- https://gist.github.com/GavinRay97/bae1d93925e55ce0a0084946f24984cf

Hope someone out there finds this information useful =)
[image]