# Prettify clang -v output

Tags: c++, c, clang

Is there any way to get clang output to insert carriage returns?  When compiling with the verbose option, I just get these huge unreadable dumps of compiler flags and paths.

Comment: Hm? Those long lines seem to exactly be the ones that are fed into Clang. All flags, for example, must occur in a single command: ""/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.7.4 -emit-obj  ..." (etc.; admittedly, for another 433 characters, but still *one command line*). There is no logical position to insert a hard return anywhere in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `popen` to start your `clang` session. Create a new command line as `clang -v` (including the space) and concatenate the arguments that you usually feed to `clang` itself. After the final argument, add `2>&1` to convert Clang's `stderr` output to regular `stdout` so `popen` can pick it up. Then loop over `popen`'s input and parse each separate line, adding extra information where you see fit.

As an example, I grabbed the entire set of flags for my local Clang using

```
clang -cc1 --help
```

and incorporated this as a single long string in my C program. Then I looped over the return results from `popen`, scanning for flags starting with `-`, and when one was found, I scanned the long flags string for this. If it found something, I write it out on a separate line in green (using ANSI escape sequences). Then I test the flags string if an argument should follow – these usually have a leading `<...>` indicator. If so, I write it out in blue. Finally, I write out the entire flag explanation line until I encounter an end-of-line.

With my very rough program called `colorclang` – 123 lines of actual code – I get output like this:

[image: colorclang output]

As it is, it tests *every* input line for possible flags so there is some mis-coloring. More exact parsing is possible; I'd have to add separate routines for the single line starting with `"/usr/bin/clang"` (for the common Clang flags), the single line starting with `"/usr/bin/ld"` (and parse the *loader* flags), and possibly the lines after each `#include ..` statement.

Pieced together with the help of [Complete list of clang flags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880812/complete-list-of-clang-flags), Steve Kemp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/646254/2564301) to [C: Run a System Command and Get Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/646241/2564301), and after deducing `clang -v` writes to `stderr`, [larsman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6900631/2564301) to [c popen won't catch stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6900577/2564301).