# Where is the complete documentation of Clang flags?

Tags: clang, compiler-flags

The references I know are here:

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html

But I can't find flags like `-msse4.1`, so is there a complete list of supported flags on *clang.llvm.org*, or do we need external documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Complete list of Clang flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880812/complete-list-of-clang-flags)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to lookup on the `-m` target flags.

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/genindex.html