# What does @ mean in this clang command in AOSP build log?

Tags: bash, clang, android-source

In `AOSP9.0.0_r30`'s build log, there are clang commands like this:

```
prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-4691093/bin/clang++ /OpenSource/Build/Android/9.0.0_r30/soong/.intermediates/bionic/libc/crtbegin_so/android_x86_64_core/crtbegin_so.o @/OpenSource/Build/Android/9.0.0_r30/soong/.intermediates/bionic/libm/libm/android_x86_64_core_shared/libm.so.rsp ......
```

FYI, it is a linking commmand.

In short, it is like:

```
clang++ path_to_file1 @path_to_file2 ......
```

What does the "`@`" mean here?

Comment: I suspect, it means "read file and use its contents as command line".

Comment: [LLVM docs | Response File](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html#response-files).

Comment: @jww Thanks a lot. Can you consider answer this question too:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55348280/where-is-the-complete-documentation-of-clang-flags. For example, what does -m32/-m64 mean? I think all these flags are the back end flags but where is the full list?

Comment: @jww Is "@"
file a norm for bash, or is it specific to gcc/clang?