# warning: unknown warning option '-Wlogical-op' did you mean '-Wlong-long'?

Tags: c++, clang++

While compiling source on Mac os using clang++ i get this warning flag. 
The full compilation options

```
-Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-old-style-cast -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-write-strings -Wreturn-type -Werror=return-type -Werror=uninitialized -Wunreachable-code -Wno-keyword-macro -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-unused-const-variable $1 $2 $3
```

Comment: Are you using a version of Clang supported by the project you're building? (Or does it perhaps not support Clang at all?)

Comment: `clang` doesn't support that flag; see [this site for instace](https://github.com/Barro/compiler-warnings) that has a list of all compiler flags.

Comment: [Complete list of clang flags?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7880812/995714)

Comment: `-Wlogical-op` is a GNU GCC gcc and g++ warning.  Clang++ does not provide that warning.