# What is the "-z" option of Clang and why is it needed?

Tags: c, macos, linker, clang

Consider the following linker-specific options of Clang:

```
-Wl,<arg>                Pass the comma separated arguments in <arg> to the linker
-Xlinker <arg>           Pass <arg> to the linker
-z <arg>                  Pass -z <arg> to the linker
```

What is meant by `Pass -z <arg> to the linker` and how does `-z <arg>` differ from `-Xlinker <arg>`?

I sometimes see `-z <arg>` used with `-Wl,<arg>` like:

```
-Wl,-z,norelro
```

But why is this needed, if arguments to `-Wl` should merely be comma-separated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880812/complete-list-of-clang-flags

Comment: Note that this sort of silliness almost always arises through compatibility. Group A invents standard A, group B invents standard B, group C invents standard C, and suddenly you find yourself needing to implement all 3 ... which is now standard D. See also https://xkcd.com/927/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why is -z used with -Wl

The following 3 commands are *exactly* equivalent:

```
clang main.c -o a.out -Wl,-z,norelro
clang main.c -o a.out -z norelro
clang main.c -o a.out -Xlinker -z -Xlinker norelro
```

They all pass `-z norelro` to the linker during the final link stage.

The first form is standard across many compilers. The second form is a tiny bit shorter, but really shouldn't be used (because using a "standard" form is always better). The third form is supported only to be compatible with GCC. It's unnecessarily verbose.

**Update:**

> Couldn't we just write `-Wl,norelro`

No: that will pass a "naked" `norelro` option to the linker, which will treat it as an input file and will complain that no such input file exists. There is (obviously) a difference between passing `-z norelro` and just `norelro`.

> Also, consider `clang ./noaslr.c -Wl,-z,-no_pie ...`

That is just a bogus command. The `-no-pie` *is* a linker option, and should not be prefixed by `-z`. It's also *not* a valid option value for the `-z` option.

**Update 2:**

> Where can I see possible values for the -z linker option?

In the manual page for `ld` *on the OS that you are targeting*. For example, on Linux the latest BFD `ld` [understands](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) the following `-z` options: `bndplt`, `call-nop-prefix=...`, `combreloc`, etc. etc.

> Also, do you have any clue why man ld on macOS doesn't show the -z linker option?

Probably because it *doesn't* support that option at all.

Comment: Thanks. But why is `-z` used with `-Wl`? Couldn't we just write `-Wl,norelro` (nothing is mentioned about `-z` in the description of `-Wl`)? Also, why is `-z` used with `-Xlinker` (they have exactly the same description)?

Comment: Also, consider `clang ./noaslr.c -Wl,-z,-no_pie -o noaslr` which results in `ld: unknown option: -z` on macOS. This only works without the `-z` option, i.e `-Wl,-no_pie`???

Comment: Thanks again. I think I understand now that the linker `ld` takes options itself using `-z <arg>` and that `clang` pass exactly `-z <arg>` to `ld` instead of only `<arg>`? Also, some arguments to the linker require `-z`, while others like `-no_pie` are passed exactly as they are (no `-z` in front)? Where can I see possible values for the `-z` linker option? Also, do you have any clue why `man ld` on macOS doesn't show the `-z` linker option?

Comment: Thanks, I guess since `clang` supports `-z` on macOS, but nothing is mentioned about that option in `ld`, then `clang` must translate it to some option that `ld` understands.